# MySQL Database Password protection

Tags: hash, mysql, salt

I am developing an industry-level web server that requires that all passwords be encrypted in some way.

The middle-ware for the server is Java-based. My only restriction is that I can't use API's like bCrypt for this. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: "My only restriction is that I can't use API's like bCrypt for this" why?

Comment: The company I work for has a policy against external APIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently three accepted password hashing algorithms (note the difference between encryption and hashing!):

- pbkdf2
- bcrypt
- scrypt

So you can use either of these three. PBKDF2 is the most supported. Storing passwords in a reversible way is considered bad practice.